# Can't get an Array of matches using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, typescript

```
const stringWithDate: string = "4/7/20 This is a date!";
const reg: RegExp = new RegExp("^(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})").compile();
const exist: boolean = reg.test(stringWithDate)
const matches: RegExpExecArray | null = reg.exec(stringWithDate);
console.log(exist);
console.log(matches);
```

I am trying to get the date (4/7/20) extracted from strngWithDate. When I log the value of 'exist' it says true but the matches array says [""]. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I know the regex isn't that good but I know it works because I tried the same in python and 
[here](https://regexr.com/). As far as I can tell it should give me "4/7/20" from stringWithDate. But isn't happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You're not allowing for the fact your backslashes are in a string literal.
2. You're not passing anything into `compile`.

### 1. Backslashes

Remember that in a string literal, a backslash is an escape character, so the `\d` in your string is an unnecessary escape of `d`, which results in just `d`. So your actual regular expression is:

```
^(d{1,2}/d{1,2}/d{1,2})
```

Use the literal form instead:

```
const reg: RegExp = /^(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})/; // No `compile`, see next point
```

Live Example:

```js
const stringWithDate/*: string*/ = "4/7/20 This is a date!";
const reg/*: RegExp*/ = /^(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})/; // No `compile`, see next point
const exist/*: boolean*/ = reg.test(stringWithDate)
const matches/*: RegExpExecArray | null*/ = reg.exec(stringWithDate);
console.log(exist);
console.log(matches);
```

### 2. `compile`

`compile` accepts a **new** expression to compile, replacing the existing expression. By not passing an expression in as an argument, you're getting the expression `(?:)`, which matches the blank at the beginning of your string.

You dont need `compile` ([spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexp.prototype.compile) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/compile)). It's an Annex B feature (supposedly only in JavaScript engines in web browsers). Here's what the spec has to say in a note about it:

> The `compile` method completely reinitializes the this object RegExp with a new pattern and flags. An implementation may interpret use of this method as an assertion that the resulting RegExp object will be used multiple times and hence is a candidate for extra optimization.

...but JavaScript engines can figure out whether a regular expression needs optimization without your telling them.

**If** you wanted to use `compile`, you'd do it like this:

```
const reg: RegExp = /x/.compile(/^(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})/);
```

The contents of the initial regular expression are completely replaced with the pattern and flags from the one passed into `compile`.

---

Side note: There's no reason for the type annotations on any of those `const`s. TypeScript will correctly infer them.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! It works now and as for the tip at the end, I'll remember it well! The only thing is the array has ["4/7/20", "4/7/20"] now. I don't understand why it's in the array two times.

Comment: @ArnabChakraborty - Because of how `exec` works: The match array contains the overall match for the entire expression at index 0, then includes matches for any capture groups within the expression starting with index 1.